# Rewrite first level subdirectory to root directory passing folder name .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an application where I pass in the customer name to determine which information to show on the page.

Previously I had it setup to be subdomain based, for example `https://client1.company.com`, `https://client2.company.com`. I would parse the subdomain to determine the customer name, and each subdomain pointed to the same set of files on the server.

I have to change this to be subdirectory based, so it would now be `https://company.com/client1/`, `https://company.com/client2/`, etc.

Is there an .htaccess rewrite rule I can use to basically rewrite any request with a subdirectory back to the root directory? This way when an ajax request goes to the server from `https://company.com/client2/` it will redirect the request to `https://company.com/ajax.php` as opposed to sending the request to `https://company.com/client2/ajax.php` and it not being found.

When loading stylesheets, etc. it would redirect `https://company.com/client1/assets/css/style.css` to `https://company.com/assets/css/style.css`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# redirection to a level up
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^[\w-]+(/.*)$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this so it's not just ajax.php? Ideally everything requested from the subfolder will be routed 1 level up (excluding a few directories I'll specify)

Comment: Yes everything can be redirected to a level up but when should it call `ajaz.php`?

Comment: Basically I'm looking to have any file like /client1/request.php, /client1/ajax.php, /client1/anything.php needs to be redirected up a level (without having to specify the file name in the .htaccess). Does that make sense?